# ¿Cómo puedo crear un vector global donde pueda ir almacenando la información que debo recolectar en el recorrido de mi aplicación?

Tags: android, android-studio, array

Estoy desarrollando un registro en android, y necesito recolectar la información, pero debo ir almacenándola en un vector para después enviar ese paquete a una base de datos, sé que debo crear una variable global, pero en realidad no sé como hacerlo, ya que desde cada activity debo ir enviando información al vector y al finalizar cuando ya esté lleno pues enviarla a la base de datos. Agradezco toda su colaboración, soy nueva en esto.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para pasar la informacion de un Activity a otro lo puedes hacer con Intent,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("llave",valor);
  startActivity(intent);
```

para obtenerla en la segunda activity

```
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (bundle!= null){
    String miVariable = bundle.getString("llave");
    //ArrayList<String> miArray = bundle.getStringArrayList("miArray");
}
```

De esta forma puedes ir pasanado la informacion de una actividad a otra ya que crear una variable global tendria que ser static final en una clase para accederla.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes crear tu propia implementación de la clase Application, en esta clase puedes declarar tu vector y modificarlo a gusto por ejemplo:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    private List<String> vector;

    //obtienes una instancia unica para todas las actividades
    public List<String> getVector(){
         if(vector == null)
             vector = new ArrayList<>();
         return vector;
    }
}
```

en el manifiesto:

```
<application
     android:name=".MyApplication"
     .
     .
     . />
```

En cada actividad:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private List<String> vector;

    public void onCreate(){
        .....
        vector = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getVector();//de esta manera obtienes la instancia única de un vector global 

    //posterior para modificar los valores has vector.add(valor); para seguir agregando valores 

    }

}
```

De aquí en adelante manipula el vector a tu antojo.

Saludos

Comment: Perdón, y entonces en cada activity como enviaría información al vector? Gracias por tu colaboración.

Comment: El vector esta declarado en la clase MyApplication que hereda de Application. Ósea que el vector es global para la aplicacion sin importar en que actividad se encuentre. Con esta línea de código 

`List<String>vector = ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getVector();`
tienes acceso a la instancia del vector si quieres agregar información has vector.add("texto");

Comment: Si pongo lo del manisfest, me sale errror, se pone en rojo.

Comment: Quitalo, luego escribe: android:name="  <-- Dale Ctrl+Spacio te tiene que salir las posibles clases. Recuerda que la clase MyApplication hereda de application sino no te aparece y te marca en rojo.